# WPF Datagrid scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using WPF Datagrid and I would like to have it autoscrolled when a new row is added. For this, I added the CollectionChanged event for the ItemsSource and it works fine.

```
private void dataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var items = (dataGrid.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>);

        if (items == null)
            return;

        items.CollectionChanged += MainWindow_CollectionChanged;
    }

private void MainWindow_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGrid.Items !=null && dataGrid.Items.Count > 0)
            dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.Items[dataGrid.Items.Count - 1]);
    }
```

The problem is I want the autoscroll feature disabled while I click on any of the scroll bars of the Datagrid. Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: As in *permanently disabled* or just while the mouse is pressed?

Comment: Disable it while the mouse is pressed on the scroll bars, then revert to the enabled state when it is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigation, I found the following simple solution. For the Datagrid, I added the scroll event.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ScrollBar.Scroll ="dataGrid_Scroll">
</DataGrid>
```

CS:

```
private void dataGrid_Scroll(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollEventArgs scrollEvent = e as ScrollEventArgs;
        if (scrollEvent != null)
        {
            if (scrollEvent.ScrollEventType == ScrollEventType.EndScroll)
            {
                isScrolling = false;
            }
            else
            {
                isScrolling = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attached property to observe the relevant ScrollBar events. Note, in the following example I am using two properties: `EnableUserScrollingObserver` in order to enable the event listeners and `IsUserScrolling` to report the current scrolling state.

```
public static class Attached
{
    public static bool GetEnableUserScrollingObserver(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(EnableUserScrollingObserverProperty);
    }

    public static void SetEnableUserScrollingObserver(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(EnableUserScrollingObserverProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableUserScrollingObserverProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EnableUserScrollingObserver", typeof(bool), typeof(Attached),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(EnableUserScrollingObserverChanged)));

    private static void EnableUserScrollingObserverChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = d as ScrollBar;
        if (s != null)
        {
            s.Scroll -= Scrollbar_Scroll;
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                s.Scroll += Scrollbar_Scroll;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Using this on anything other than a ScrollBar sucks
            throw new InvalidOperationException("EnableUserScrollingObserver is designed for ScrollBar elements!");
        }
    }

    static void Scrollbar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = sender as ScrollBar;
        switch (e.ScrollEventType)
        {
            case ScrollEventType.EndScroll:
                SetIsUserScrolling(s, false);
                break;
                /* All the things handled by default
            case ScrollEventType.First:
                break;
            case ScrollEventType.LargeDecrement:
                break;
            case ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement:
                break;
            case ScrollEventType.Last:
                break;
            case ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement:
                break;
            case ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement:
                break;
            case ScrollEventType.ThumbPosition:
                break;
            case ScrollEventType.ThumbTrack:
                break;
                 */
            default:
                SetIsUserScrolling(s, true);
                break;
        }
    }



    public static bool GetIsUserScrolling(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsUserScrollingProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsUserScrolling(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsUserScrollingProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsUserScrollingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsUserScrolling", typeof(bool), typeof(Attached),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

Then connect the scroll information to your viewmodel `IsScrolling` property

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
    <Setter Property="local:Attached.EnableUserScrollingObserver" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="local:Attached.IsUserScrolling" Value="{Binding IsScrolling,Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
</Style>
```

Finally, in your `MainWindow_CollectionChanged` method, add a check for the `IsScrolling` property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a more simple solution, by using the ScrollBar.Scroll event.

Comment: Yep, that `Scroll` event is the core of my solution after all. I just built a blob of code around it so it can be used with a viewmodel instead of code behind :)